# auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist on hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I am using hive 1.2.0 and hadoop 2.6.0. whenever I am running hive on my machine... select query works fine but in case of `count(*)` it shows following error:

> Diagnostic Messages for this Task: Container launch failed for
>   container_1434646588807_0001_01_000005 :
>   **org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidAuxServiceException: The auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist**     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.instantiateException(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.deSerialize(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$Container.launch(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:155)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$EventProcessor.run(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:369)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
>   Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
>   Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please use this in yarn-site.xml; when you set the framework to use as yarn, it starts to look for these values.

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Should be yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class ?

Comment: I used yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class , it worked !

Comment: @AravindKrishnakumar did you restart Hive after that or?

Comment: @Anil did you restart Hive after that or?

Answer (score 0):

When you set the framework to use as yarn, it starts to look for these values. I was facing same error for Java Map reduce. When i set configuration as following :

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn");

Container launch failed for container_1448364218966_0001_01_000002 : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidAuxServiceException: The auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.instantiateException(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.deSerialize(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$Container.launch(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$EventProcessor.run(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:369)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I resolved it by setting following:

```
<configuration>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->


<property>
               <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
               <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

~

Comment: did you restart Hive after that or what steps did you perform?